# SQL Artists similar

Tags: sql

I have 5 tables :

```
 Artists (artistID: int, name: varchar(255))
 SimilarArtists (artistID: int, simArtistID: int, weight: int)
 Albums (albumID: int, artistID: int, name: varchar(255))
 Tracks (trackID: int, artistID: int, name: varchar(255), length: int)
 TrackLists (albumID: int, trackID: int, trackNum: int)
```

Find the names of all Artists who are more similar to Mogwai than to Nirvana (meaning the weight of their similarity to Mogwai is greater)

```
SELECT Artists.name
FROM Artists, SimiliarArtists
WHERE Artists.ArtistID = SimiliarArtists.ArtistID AND
SimiliarArtists.weight > (
SELECT SimiliarArtists.weight
FROM Artists, SimiliarArtists
WHERE Artists.name = ‘Mogwai’ AND
Artists.ArtistID = SimiliarArtists.ArtistID);
```

Comment: There is not enough information to answer this question.  Please provide some sample data.  In particular, is the table `SimilarArtists` commutative -- that is, if (A, B) is in the table is (B, A) ?  And, is not being in the table evidence that similarity is `0` or are all pairs in the table?

Answer (score 0):

brute force query :), please check for null values

```
select * from (  
  select 
    (select weight from similiarartists sa, artists aa where sa.simartistid = aa.artistid and sa.artistid = a.artistid and aa.name = 'Nirvana') nirvana,
    (select weight from similiarartists sa, artists aa where sa.simartistid = aa.artistid and sa.artistid = a.artistid and aa.name = 'Mogwai') mogwai,
    a.*
 from artists a
) where a.mogwai > a.nirvana
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt at this;

```
select *
from artists a
left join 
(select sa.artistid, weight from similiarartists sa, artists aa where sa.simartistid =  aa.artistid and sa.artistid = a.artistid and aa.name = 'Nirvana') nirvana on nirvana.artistid = a.artistid
left join 
(select sa.artistid, weight from similiarartists sa, artists aa where sa.simartistid = aa.artistid and sa.artistid = a.artistid and aa.name = 'Mogwai') mogwai on mogwai.artistid = a.artistid
where mogwai.weight > nirvana.weight;
```